# AndroidStudio : E/AndroidLogcatService Error on only one device

Tags: java, android, android-studio

getting error message in Android Studio Logcat Window and logs does not appears after it

```
E/AndroidLogcatService: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Any Solution ?

Comment: Hi Sandro! To be able to answer your question, you will need to add more information and what you are trying to do. At least the version of Android Studio you are using, the version of plugins used the name of the device that works and the name of the device that doesn't work. It is also a good idea to write down the steps needed to reproduce the error. Regards, Lars

Comment: want to know, why this error occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced a similar issue recently. I had an AVD device that I edited -- changed the name and platform version. Afterward I was seeing this same error. In my case, I simply recreated the AVD device and the error went away.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with adb. You need to write in the terminal `adb kill-server` and then `adb connect IP:PORT`. It helped me.

Comment: @olajide Navigate to /home/<username>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools and run the command. I recommend adding it to path if you use adb frequently

Comment: Instead of reconnecting through IP:PORT using adb start-server also works